# RequireJS optimization with define functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I want to build my project to one file. I have three files.

test2.js:

```
define(
  'test2',
  ['test3.js'],
  function (t2) {
      // test 2
  }
);
```

test3.js:

```
define(
  'test3',
  [],
  function () {
      // test 3
  }
);
```

and main file test1.js:

```
require(
  ['test2.js'],
  function (t2) {
      // test 1
  }
);
```

Build config:

```
({
  baseUrl: '.',
  name: 'test1',
  out: 'built.js',
  optimize: "none"
})
```

Result:

```
define(
  'test2',
  ['test3.js'],
  function (t2) {
      // test 2
  }
);

define("test2.js", function(){});

require(
  ['test2.js'],
  function (t2) {
    // test 1
  }
);

define("test1", function(){});
```

So I dont's see the test3.js code there. Does r.js work only with **require** dependencies? Can I make it build with **define** dependencies?

Comment: *"When I trying to compile it a get smth about it:"* Huh? Can you clarify that sentence a bit? Are you saying you get an error? (If so, quote it.) Or that you get output like what you follow that sentence with? Or...?

Comment: Show your RequireJS runtime configuration and your build configuration too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.js` suffix for dependencies, and don't use named modules.

`File: test2.js:`

```
define(['test3'],
  function (t2) {
      // test 2
  }
);
```

`File: test3.js:`

```
define([],
  function () {
      // test 3
  }
);
```

`File: test1.js:`

```
require(
  ['test2'],
  function (t2) {
      // test 1
  }
);
```